# mocking http requests for API's in protractor

Tags: angularjs, mocking, protractor, automated-tests

I have followed a few tutorials online for mocking http requests with protractor but have been unsuccessful in each case for one of two (or both reasons):

1. The library requires a `<script>` include which I do not want.
2. The tutorial is really vague and often outdated.

Can anyone shed some light on how (if) they are doing / have done this before? Thanks very much

Comment: can you post some of what you tried so far?

Comment: Also an example of what exactly you are trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: your using Jasmine also?

Answer (score 1):

Are you mocking an Angular application? 
I have used httpbackend-proxy a lot for mocking: https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy

But it does require you to have the app have a module of ngMockE2E and include angular-mocks.js in the list of scripts.

What is the issue with using the script of angular-mocks?   Or what kind of mocking are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I am using jasmine and am mocking for an angular app. The backend exists, but ive been instructed to do this so if the api changes or is down the tests can still run and the UI will still handle things correctly. The problem is that it makes not one, but a series of api calls which in my opinion makes this task a lot harder, if not impossible